# About sequences & identifier

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

I want to change **Invoice format** in which 2015/06/0001 , where year is **current year**, Month is set to **next month of worked out month**  & Last is unique count for that month.
  I have tried with sequences but month can not set to next of worked out.
I have set prefix

> ABC/%(year)s/%(month)s/

but I want month as a next month of worked out.

Answer (score 0):

Invoice sequences are a little odd because they come via the account.move entry rather than a simple one like the sale.order.

However, you could either override the required method in account.move/account.invoice or if you look in ir_sequence.py in the account module there is an example of overriding the appropriate method to control the sequence.